# ES6 docready - Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _docready2.default) is not a function

Tags: import, ecmascript-6

Why do I this error below, for this [node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docready)?

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _docready2.default) is not a function
    at Object.1.docready (bundle.min.js:32)
```

My main file:

```
import docReady from 'docready';

docReady(function() {
    console.log("DOM is ready. Let's party");
});
```

Comment: The docReady script you're referencing (that I wrote) is not in an ES6 module and does not export anything.  It's just a direct script that you can use in a `<script>` tag and it defines a single global function name `docReady`.

Comment: @jfriend00 got it. thank you! :-)

Comment: It could be put into an ES6 module with only a few lines of code if you wanted.

Comment: @jfriend00 that would be wonderful! can you provide the code and update the npm?

Comment: I'm not ready to make the Github repository ES6 only so I don't think I'll change that right now.  The main point of this code is to work with a wide variety of browsers (including older browsers).  You could modify your own version for your own use.  If you knew you had an ES6-capable browser, most of what's in that function is not needed.

Comment: @jfriend00 that's ok. i will do that myself. thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docReady script you're referencing (that I wrote) is not in an ES6 module and does not export anything.  It's just a direct script that you can use in a `<script>` tag and it defines a single global function name `docReady`.

It could be put into an ES6 module and export the main function with only a few lines of code if you wanted.

Here's the origin of that code on stack overflow: [pure JavaScript equivalent to jQuery's $.ready() how to call a function when the page/dom is ready for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the/9899701#9899701)